# Вычисление дроби рекурсией

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия

Дано действительное число x!=0. Вычислить дробь, используя рекурсивную подпрограмму:

[image: формула]

При вычислении дроби через рекурсию даже с double считает только как функцию y= x/x^2. Как сделать расчёт более точным, чтобы часть, в которой рекурсия, тоже учитывалась?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int func(float i, float x)
{
    i*=2;
    if (i < 256)
        return ((x*x + i) / func(i, x));
    else return((x*x + (i / x*x)));
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    float x;
    cout << "Введите X";
    cin >> x;
    float y;
    int i = 1;
    y = x/func(i,x);
    cout << "Ответ:" << y<<"\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: x*x + i / func(i, x)

Comment: используй дабл, он для расчетов получше будет.

Comment: Даже с дабл считает только как функцию y= x/x^2. Как сделать расчёт более точным, чтобы часть, в которой рекурсия, тоже влияла на ответ?

Comment: Повернуть картинку перед загрузкой - не?

Comment: Совет на будущее: если хотите, чтобы ответ был более точным, можно попробовать "вывернуть" дробь и получить её в виде классической рациональной дроби: `y=(x^16+508*x^12+41664*x^8+634880*x^4+1048576)/(x*(x^16+510*x^12+42672*x^8+714240*x^4+2031616))` Далее считать по схеме Горнера или иным способом, минимизирующим число действий. Плюс от рекурсии избавитесь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не злоупотребляйте скобками

```
double func(int i, double x)
{
  i = i * 2;
  if (i < 256)
    return x * x + i / func(i, x);
  else 
    return x * x + i / x * x;
}
```

и не приводите результат функции к целому.

```js
function func(i, x)
{
  i = i * 2;
  if (i < 256)
    return x * x + i / func(i, x);
  else 
    return x * x + i / x * x;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#calculate").click(function(){
    var inp = parseFloat($("#valueIn").val());
    var out = inp / func(1, inp);
    $("#valueOut").val(out);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Input:<input id="valueIn" type="text" />
<br/><br/>
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<br/><br/>
Output:<input id="valueOut" type="text" />
```

Comment: Ответ принят, но `i / x * x` - ошибка. Должно быть `i / (x * x)`. А рядом написано "Не злоупотребляйте скобками". :)

Answer (score 1):

Основная ошибка кроется в описании рекурсивной функции

```
 int func(float i, float x)
```

Указано что функция возвращает результат типа `int`. Т.е. в вашем случае получается что любой результат приводится к целому числу.

Таким образом теряется точность вычислений.

Чтобы исправить это нужно указать что функция возвращает `float`. Или же для большой точности стоит поменять все `float` на `double`

Comment: Обе ошибки - основные: тип возвращаемого значения и скобки в `return ((x*x + i) / func(i, x));`.